# How do I configure multicast?

Tags: networking

Can some one please explain the steps required to configure a multicast in Ubuntu?
I have a simple program taken from Internet. I get errors when I execute the client program.  I get the error as:

```
Opening datagram socket....OK.  
Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.  
Binding datagram socket...OK.  
Adding multicast group error: No such device:
```

When I execute the server program I get the error as:

```
Opening the datagram socket...OK.
Setting local interface error: Cannot assign requested address
```

I am using Ubuntu to run the program.  I have two different laptops but connected via the same network. I am using wireless network to perform the above operation.

Client Program

```
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <arpa/inet.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  


struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sd < 0)
{
perror("Opening datagram socket error");
exit(1);
}
else
printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");

/* Enable SO_REUSEADDR to allow multiple instances of this */
/* application to receive copies of the multicast datagrams. */
{
int reuse = 1;
if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
{
perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
close(sd);
exit(1);
}
else
printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");
}

/* Bind to the proper port number with the IP address */
/* specified as INADDR_ANY. */
memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
{
perror("Binding datagram socket error");
close(sd);
exit(1);
}
else
printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");

/* Join the multicast group 226.1.1.1 on the local 203.106.93.94 */
/* interface. Note that this IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option must be */
/* called for each local interface over which the multicast */
/* datagrams are to be received. */
group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.0");
group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("233.106.93.94");
if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
{
perror("Adding multicast group error");
close(sd);
exit(1);
}
else
printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");

/* Read from the socket. */
datalen = sizeof(databuf);
if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)
{
perror("Reading datagram message error");
close(sd);
exit(1);
}
else
{
printf("Reading datagram message...OK.\n");
printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);
}
return 0;
}
```

Server Program

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
int sd;
char databuf[1024] = "Multicast test message lol!";
int datalen = sizeof(databuf);

int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
/* Create a datagram socket on which to send. */
sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sd < 0)
{
  perror("Opening datagram socket error");
  exit(1);
}
else
  printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");

/* Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a */
/* group address of 225.1.1.1 and port 5555. */
memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.0");
groupSock.sin_port = htons(4321);

/* Disable loopback so you do not receive your own datagrams.
{
char loopch = 0;
if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loopch, sizeof(loopch)) < 0)
{
perror("Setting IP_MULTICAST_LOOP error");
close(sd);
exit(1);
}
else
printf("Disabling the loopback...OK.\n");
}
*/

/* Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams. */
/* The IP address specified must be associated with a local, */
/* multicast capable interface. */
localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("233.106.93.94");
if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)
{
  perror("Setting local interface error");
  exit(1);
}
else
  printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");
/* Send a message to the multicast group specified by the*/
/* groupSock sockaddr structure. */
/*int datalen = 1024;*/
if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
{perror("Sending datagram message error");}
else
  printf("Sending datagram message...OK\n");

/* Try the re-read from the socket if the loopback is not disable
if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)
{
perror("Reading datagram message error\n");
close(sd);
exit(1);
}
else
{
printf("Reading datagram message from client...OK\n");
printf("The message is: %s\n", databuf);
}
*/
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us what this "Simple Program" is?

Answer (score 3):

At a glance, `group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("233.106.93.94");` looks like it has an incorrect IP address, as it should be adding the IP address which is on the interface itself.

The IP address used in the example was `203.106.93.94`, you should probably replace that with the IP address which you have on eth0 or similar.